# Color segments of a custom shape in a div

Tags: html, css, graph, charts

I'm trying to colorize parts of a half-circle, to use it as a pie-chart of sorts.

```css
.half-circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  /* background-color: gold; */
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  border: 30px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle">
  <span style="width:100%; background-color: red !important;">Test</span>
</div>
```

Any pointers as to how I might achieve this?
Making a span or div with a width % didn't seem to achieve the desired effect.

[image: An example of what I'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `radial-gradient` and `conic-gradient`, assign this style to a div :

```
#circle {
       width: 20%;
       height: 200px;
       background: radial-gradient(white 40%, transparent 41%), conic-gradient(#1a6abc 0% 33%, #7bd2b6 0% 66%, #e74c3c 0% 100%);
       border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

[image]